# How to resize tab width automatically in HTML5

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to automatically resize the container based on `<div>`. If there are 4 `<div>` inside container then it looks fine but if there is only 1 `<div>` then there will be plenty of space in right side. So wanted to adjust container size according to `<div>`. How can I achieve this? Please help me.

main page looks like this
[image: Main]

When there are 4 panels it fits perfectly fine like this

[image: 1st]

When there are 2 panels then there is plenty of space in the right side which which is marked by color. I want to adjust the container width here automatically.

[image: 2nd]

```
 <div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="ATab">
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Select">Select</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Criteria">Criteria</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="Select" class=" tab-pane fade in active"></div>
            <div id="Criteria" class="tab-pane fade"></div>

                  <div class="container active col-md-3 col-sm-6 ">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">First Name</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="container active col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">Last Name</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flexbox for this behavior. Check this [codepen](https://codepen.io/tusharshukla/pen/GxQEKa) for demo.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="parent">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.parent {
  background-color: orange;
}

.parent ul.nav {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.parent ul.nav li {
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.parent ul.nav li:last-child {
  border: 0px;
}
```

Hope this would help!

**EDIT 1:**
Check this other [codepen](https://codepen.io/tusharshukla/pen/GxQEKa) for demo.

```css
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0;
}

.parent {
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 20px;
}

.parent .tabFrame .itemContainer {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.parent .tabFrame .myItem {
  background-color: grey;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px; /* can be any fixed width */
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="tabFrame">
    <div>Tab area</div>
    <div class="itemContainer">
      <div class="myItem">Item 1</div>
      <div class="myItem">Item 2</div>
      <div class="myItem">Item 3</div>
      <div class="myItem">Item 4</div>
    </div>    
  </div>
  
  <div class="tabFrame">
    <div>Tab area</div>
    <div class="itemContainer">
      <div class="myItem">Item 1</div>
      <div class="myItem">Item 2</div>
      <div class="myItem">Item 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="tabFrame">
    <div>Tab area</div>
    <div class="itemContainer">
      <div class="myItem">Item 1</div>
      <div class="myItem">Item 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="tabFrame">
    <div>Tab area</div>
    <div class="itemContainer">
      <div class="myItem">Item 1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT: 2**

See this [codepen](http://codepen.io/tusharshukla/pen/rdJdZK)

```css
.myTab {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: -1px;
}

.myTab .tab-pane .myPanel {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

.myPanel {
  min-width: 200px;
}

#ATab {
  border-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div>
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="ATab">
        <li class="active">
          <a data-toggle="tab" href="#Select">Select</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a data-toggle="tab" href="#Criteria">Criteria</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content clearfix myTab">
        <br>
        <div id="Select" class=" tab-pane fade in active clearfix">
          <div class="panel panel-default myPanel">
            <div class="panel-heading">First Name</div>
          </div>

          <div class="panel panel-default myPanel">
            <div class="panel-heading">Last Name</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Criteria" class="tab-pane fade">
          <div class="panel panel-default myPanel">
            <div class="panel-heading">First Name</div>
          </div>

          <div class="panel panel-default myPanel">
            <div class="panel-heading">Last Name</div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="panel panel-default myPanel">
            <div class="panel-heading">First Name</div>
          </div>

          <div class="panel panel-default myPanel">
            <div class="panel-heading">Last Name</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not what I wanted. I have edited my question and added some image file which I think can give some clear idea what I wanted. In 1st Image, there are 4 panels so it fits perfectly fine in the container. But  If you see in Second Image, there is only 2 panels but still there is plenty of space in the right side which I do not want. It should automatically adjust based on the panel in criteria section. I hope I have clarified.

Comment: See my updated answer and let me know if this is what you want!

Comment: Sorry Tushar. Please read my comment.I want to automatically resize the container based on `<div>` inside container. If there are 4 `<div>` inside container then it looks fine but if there is only  1 `<div>` then there will be plenty of space in right side. So wanted to adjust container size according to `<div>`.

Comment: Yupp, that's what I understood and this is what is happening in the codepen I've shown. The container box is adjusting its width based on contents inside. If the divs are wider than the parent then it will overflow. I'm not sure what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: Appreciated if you can take my code and do the needful. I am looking forward to your help.

Comment: I guess this is the one you're looking for: https://codepen.io/tusharshukla/pen/rdJdZK

Comment: Yes Tushar. This is what i wanted. Thank you so much. please update the answer. i will accept it so that other can get benefit of this. Thank you once again.

Comment: If you feel that this question is useful to other future readers on this site then can you please up vote this. Thank you!

Comment: I need your help. I followed your solution and is working fine. But when I tried the same thing in `Collapse`, it is not working in mobile view. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try using css flexbox to get rid of unwanted spaces.

```css
.nav {
  display:flex;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color:white;
}
li {
  background-color:#232323;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 20px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
li.active{
  background-color:gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div>
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="ATab">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Select">Select</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Criteria">Criteria</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="Select" class=" tab-pane fade in active"></div>
        <div id="Criteria" class="tab-pane fade"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The flex: 1 1 auto on the li makes the li fill up any remaining space on the main flex axis (horizontal line because the default flex direction is row)

You can read up on flex box : 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex/

Comment: This is not what I wanted. I have edited my question and added some image file which I think can give some clear idea what I wanted. In 1st Image, there are 4 panels so it fits perfectly fine in the container. But  If you see in Second Image, there is only 2 panels but still there is plenty of space in the right side which I do not want. It should automatically adjust based on the panel in criteria section. I hope I have clarified.